# Moving information between databases

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm on Postgres, and have two databases on the same machine, and I'd like to move some data from database Source to database Dest.

```
Database Source:
Table User has a primary key
Table Comments has a primary key
Table UserComments is a join table with two foreign keys for User and Comments
```

Dest looks just like Source in structure, but already has information in User and Comments tables that needs to be retained.

I'm thinking I'll probably have to do this in a few steps.

Step 1, I would dump Source into a file using the Postgres Copy command.

Step 2, In Dest I would add a temporary second_key column to both User and Comments, and a new SecondUserComments join table.

Step 3, I would import the dumped file into Dest using Copy again, with the keys input into the second_key columns.

Step 4, I would add rows to UserComments in Dest based on the contents of SecondUserComments, only using the real primary keys this time. Could this be done with a SQL command or would I need a script?

Step 5, delete the SecondUserComments table and remove the second_key columns.

Does this sound like the best way to do this, or is there a better way I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/dblink.html) to connect from one database to the other and just insert the records and columns you need. Then you don't have to change the datamodel, don't have to do a pg_dump, just some good old SQL.

Comment: How could I avoid changing the datamodel given that I'm also trying to import a join table that is joining on primary keys I'm going to need to change?